# python find and substitute by math.fabs

Tags: python, regex

I need to eval a math expression in python, the given string is like:

```
|667 + (-940.11)| / (-825) / (-168) / |(-367) * (-836)|
```

Here the '|' pairs indicate absolute value. I need to substitute them and get:

```
math.fabs(667 + (-940.11)) / (-825) / (-168) / math.fabs((-367) * (-836))
```

Can I do this with regular expression? Like re.sub(pattern, replacement,string)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) would work well here:

```
>>> import re
>>> line = "|667 + (-940.11)| / (-825) / (-168) / |(-367) * (-836)|"
>>> re.sub(r"\|(.*?)\|", r"math.fabs(\1)", line)
'math.fabs(667 + (-940.11)) / (-825) / (-168) / math.fabs((-367) * (-836))'
>>>
```

Below is a breakdown of the Regex syntax used in the first part:

```
\|          #  |
(.*?)       #  A capture group that matches zero or more characters non-greedily
\|          #  |
```

And here is a breakdown for the second part:

```
math.fabs(  #  math.fabs(
\1          #  The text captured by (.*?)
)           #  )
```

If you would like some more information on the Regex syntax used above, you can look [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax).

Comment: Lol, in "math.fabs(\1)", what is meaning of \1 ?

Comment: @Jun - `\1` will be the text captured by `(.*?)`.  See my edit.

Comment: Thanks! But how about absolute inside an absolute, i.e.,

Comment: ||2.24 / (-99)| + 29|

Comment: @Jun - Your question didn't mention recursive pattern matching, so my answer will not work for that.  If your inputs can become that complex, you will need to build a parser, such as a [recursive decent parser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser), that handles recursion in the input.